# Cannot implement interface because does not have matching returning type for Task<Custom class> method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage

I am working on a .NETCore web API project, on Microsoft Azure storage services.

I have a service layer BlobService which is implementing IBlobService interface

```
public interface IBlobService
{
        public Task<BlobInfo> GetBlobAsync(string name);
       
}
```

Where BlobInfo is a custom class:

```
public class BlobInfo
    {
        public BlobInfo(Stream content, string contentType)
        {
            Content = content;
            ContentType = contentType;
        }

        public Stream Content { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
    }
```

The BlobService service:

```
public class BlobService : IBlobService
    {
        public readonly BlobServiceClient _blobServiceClient;
        public BlobService(BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient)
        {
            _blobServiceClient = blobServiceClient;
        }

        public async Task<BlobInfo> GetBlobAsync(string name)
        {
            var containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("videos");
            var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(name);
            var blobDownloadInfo = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
            return new BlobInfo(blobDownloadInfo.Value.Content, blobDownloadInfo.Value.ContentType);

        }

    }
```

In this layer an error is showing up which in short says that **the return type of the Task <BlobInfo> GetBlobAsync method is not correct**, I cannot understand why, please help!

[image: error in implementing interface]

Comment: Please add errors as text, not image (if you so can).

Comment: Remove `public` from your interface method definition.

Comment: @Fildor I have also written my query but just in case someone wants to see the exact error I added image.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev I removed it but it's still not working.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yS0oUm

Comment: Or maybe you have more than one `BlobInfo` defined?  In short it might be conflicting names, or you might need to try doing a Clean and Rebuild.

Comment: @madreflection No i have not defined Task<T>. The project is in the very initial phase.

Comment: @juharr No, it's only defined once by me (hopefully not a library method/function)

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay you need to add a connection string to any Azure account(if you have)

Comment: @KartikRai5-YrIDDCompSci Yes, but that's not really relevant to this question..

Comment: @juharr Thank you very much, in the interface I had a library using Azure.Storage.Blobs; which has a predefined method blobinfo, thus was producing conflicting names. I renamed my model to BlobInformation and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved, the interface had Azure.Storage.Blobs library included which has pre-defined method BlobInfo, which conflicted names with my model BlobInfo. Hence it just needed renaming the model/exclusion of that library.